# Help finding the $n$th term of a sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if there are generic formulas or shortcuts or something that will help me find the $n$th term of a sequence when you are given several terms.

For example, one of my questions which I am struggling to find a formula for is as follows:

> Find the $n$th term of a sequence whose first several terms are given.
>
> $8,\frac{1}{9},10,\frac{1}{11},12,\frac{1}{13}$,...

Comment: $(7+n)^{-1^{n+1}}$

Comment: thanks but how did you get that, did you just think or is there a formula or way to get it?

Comment: I just stared at it for a while and thought a few that may work out, it's easier to see if you write all the $1/a$ as $a^{-1}$.

Comment: When I was trying to solve it I realized that by using a negative exponent and adding one I would get the next result. The problem I had was finding out how to make the sign always positive. So what I had was $(7+n)^{-1}$ but I didn't think of putting the -1 to the power of n+1

Comment: @TheNewGuy: It is not necessary to realize that you can do that. It is enough that you can see the pattern and express it as *S.Panja-1729* has done in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the odd terms, they are just $2k + 1 + 7$. Then the denominator of the even terms are $2k + 7$. Now we only need to modify this observation by presenting the fraction part, which can be fulfilled by adding the exponents of $(-1)$ on the shoulder of the previous terms.

Hence the general term is given by:
$$(n + 7)^{(-1)^{n + 1}}$$

Comment: Why is the downvote???

Comment: Because it cannot be shown. It can only be guessed. I can equally validly guess the next term to be $8$, because '**obviously**' the sequence repeats every $6$ terms as 'indicated' by the ellipses.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I'm not the downvoter, but if I had to guess, it's because they don't see how to show that. It doesn't look possible to show at all. It looks like you basically eyeballed it.

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer. I hope the downvoter can compensate the vote. As I think the answer itself suggests how I came up with the answer.

Comment: If you don't say "can be shown" I will of course remove the downvote. (After any edit votes can be retracted.)

Comment: I know that putting the -1 to the power of n+1 works, but I can't visually come up with that lol

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n=\begin{cases}7+n\text{ when $n$ is odd }\\\frac{1}{7+n}\text{ when $n$ is even }\end{cases}$$